# JS in Rails App only loads the first time

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails

I am using a fade effect on some links on my applications home page. This is being accomplished by some JQuery:

**javascripts/pages.js**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.home_tile_text').hide().removeClass('text').addClass('text-js');
    $('.home_tile_overlay').hide().removeClass('overlay').addClass('overlay-js');

    $('.home_tile').mouseenter(function(){
        $(this).find('.text-js').finish().hide().fadeIn();
         $(this).find('.overlay-js').finish().hide().fadeIn();
    });
    $('.home_tile').mouseleave(function(){
        $(this).find('.text-js').finish().show().fadeOut();
         $(this).find('.overlay-js').finish().show().fadeOut();
    });
});
```

This all works great when I fire up the app for the first time. However, if I navigate away from the home page, when I come back, the fade effect no longer works until I "refresh" the page. Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is probably because of Rails 4's new feature [Turbolinks](https://github.com/rails/turbolinks/). Turbolinks reduces server requests from the client by only updating the parts of the page that change. This means that `document.ready` (or `$(document).ready` in jQuery) doesn't get called again when loading new pages.

One solutions is to just remove the `gem 'turbolinks'` in your gemfile and `require turbolinks` in your application.js, thereby disabling turbolinks, but an easier fix is to just add `require jquery.turbolinks` in the application.js file which includes a turbolinks script that patches the problem by calling `$(document).ready` on every turbolinks call.

For more, refer to the [jQuery section in the turbolinks readme](https://github.com/rails/turbolinks/#jqueryturbolinks).