# Rails4: "scrollTop" doesn't work every other click

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, coffeescript

`scrollTop` doesn't work every other click (every second click).

I use `will_paginate` at the bottom of the page.

When I click on a link, the page is refreshed and the display position is at the bottom of the page.
Then I click on a link to another page, the page is refreshed and the display position is at the top of the page as I expect.

For example,
When I click the link to page 2, the page 2 is displayed but the display position remains at the bottom.
When I click the link to page 5, the page 5 is displayed and the display position is at the top as I expect.
When I click the link to page 6, the page 6 is displayed but the display position remains at the bottom.
When I click the link to page 8, the page 8 is displayed and the display position is at the top as I expect.
...

I have tried the followings, I had the same result.

\assets\javascripts\calendars.js.coffee

`$('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, 'slow')`

`$('body').animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, 'slow')`

`$('html, body').scrollTop()`

`$(document).scrollTop()`

`$(window).scrollTop()`

`$(window).scrollTop(0)`

\views\calendars\index.html.erb

```
...
<%= will_paginate @calendar %>
...
```

How should I edit my code?

Comment: Maybe you can have a look on this subject http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18555020/js-in-rails-app-only-loads-the-first-time

Comment: Thank you for your advice, @Benjamin Benoudis. The subject is helpful to me!